# Call Soap Service From a Windows Service

Tags: c#, soap, windows-services

I am consuming a Soap service **http://example.com/soap/webservice.php** in my desktop application . i created a separate class library Included the service and used this class library to consume it in my main application which i working fine.

Here is the code i am using:

```
MyService.PushServerWSPortTypeClient obj = new MyService.PushServerWSPortTypeClient();

string result = obj.auth(apiId, UserName, Password);
```

This is working perfect.

But when i use this service in my windows service i am getting the exception:

> > There was no endpoint listening at http://exmaple.com/soap/webservice.php that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

I know what this exception means that it is unable to find endpoint of it in my service, but in my class library endpoints are mentioned in it's **app.config** and i also added these endpoints in my windows service app.config as well.

Here is the code from **app.config**:

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
              <binding name="PushServerWSBinding" />
          </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
          <endpoint address="http://example.com/soap/webservice.php"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PushServerWSBinding"
              contract="MyService.PushServerWSPortType" name="PushServerWSPort" />
      </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

### Inner Exception Message :

> > The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.example.com'

### Stack Trace :

> > at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
> >        at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
> >        at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()

Comment: Can you hit the endpoint in a browser on the machine the service is running on? On the face of it it looks like the windows service is unable to resolve the domain name of the web service endpoint.

Comment: @BenRobinson when i access **http://example.com/soap/webservice.php** it works in browser on that machine but when i write only this **http://example.com** it says **The requested URL / was not found on this server.**, is it this causing issue?

Comment: @BenRobinson here is the exact url if you need that :http://api.clickatell.com/soap/webservice.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging one complete day,Today we contacted our Networks Department for this weird issue and  we came to know that When we use Desktop Application to call any **SOAP** or **WCF** Service the request goes through Proxy Server, but in the case of **Windows Service** the request goes through **System Gateway/Firewall** and on Firewall port **80** was blocked, due to which the request was unable to call server.

When we opened the port 80 for the service specific url it started wroking normally.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your browser uses some proxy where your code does not (or use different one).

If it is the case make sure to set WebClient.Proxy property to match one in the browser, making use of the WebProxy class using

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) 
{ 
  webClient.Proxy = new WebProxy("myproxy.com"); 
  result= webClient.DownloadString(someURL);
}
```

If not sure, try out his [DNS-Testing](http://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx) link. It is unlikely, but possible if browser uses different DNS than your code.

Comment: i am not sure about it BTW